# Парсинг цен

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

На яндекс маркете есть телефон, который находится [тут](http://market.yandex.ru/model.xml?modelid=7187687&hid=91491&int_lnk=p-goods-img).
Как мне спарсить цену и записать в текстовое поле?

Comment: А у самого есть соображения?

Comment: @Sergey4590, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.


Можно вообще пытаться не задавать одинаковых вопросов и не пытаться даже вникнуть в суть проблемы?

Тут не чат, тут форум.

Comment: Пишу приложение под IOS.Каталог товаров.Возникла проблема с парсером цен.Не могу написать парсер цен.Помогите кто может.

Comment: у яндекс маркета есть api http://api.yandex.ru/market/content/doc/dg/reference/all-methods.xml, делаете нужный запрос -> получаете ответ ввиде xml или json -> парсите, проще некуда ;)

Comment: А без API можно?

Comment: смотрим HTML код страницы, находим там такой тег: <span class="b-prices__num">2&nbsp;519</span>
из него выбираем 2&nbsp;519 , удаляем из этого &nbsp;, получаем 2519

Comment: не может быть!там цена телефона в этих скопках 13395.вот как мне ее взять и записать в текстовое поле

Comment: @Sergey4590 Ставьте пробелы после знаков препинания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двумя путями можете пойти вы, либо через методы стандартные то есть NSXMLParser задействовать, читать тут: [How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project). Либо применить [TBXML parser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html). И стоит еще зачитать это: [NSXMLParser Class Reference](http://tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html).

Comment: А можно как нибудь попроще?мне только цену надо взять с яндекс маркета.

Comment: Неужели все так сложно?

Comment: это по вашему сложно? особенно последний вариант...

Comment: Я смог только написать программу, которая берет html код страницы. Но никак не могу взять только цену. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: минут 20 назад я тут дал ответ http://hashcode.ru/questions/130500/парсер-html-кода?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=130775#130775  как просто разобрать NSString, куда легче я уже не знаю.

Comment: А почему нельзя взять весь контент с яндекс маркета и красиво по полочкам разложить?

Comment: Ну вот тогда и юзайте по полной категорию. Вырезайте из строки то что вам необходимо.

Comment: Перенесите все в один ViewController, получите мракобесие, но все будет в одном классе, а что собственно пугает вас в категории?

Comment: Я программирую в Xcode как мне добавить категорию?